# Laravel 6 nav tabs cannot navigate into tab only shown in url (myweb/pages#tab1)

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4, navbar

i can't navigate into tabs pages only it show in URL (myweb/pages#tab1 .. myweb/pages/#tab2 ..)
please help me 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB7lu.png)

```
    <div class="card-body">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#page1" role="tab" aria-controls="page1"
                aria-selected="true">page one</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#page2" role="tab" aria-controls="page2"
                aria-selected="false">page two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#page3" role="tab" aria-controls="page3"
                aria-selected="false">page three</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="page1" role="tabpanel">
page one    
</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page2" role="tabpanel" >
page two
 </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page3" role="tabpanel">
page three
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes bootsrap 4.1.3

Comment: Have you included the jQuery and bootstrap.js?

Comment: i'm using adminlte3

Comment: So check that js files have loaded correctly

Comment: it works correctly thnaaaaaaak you  so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Bootstrap from that link work perfect for my and i try this on your problem and i can navigate

Comment: iam using adminlte3